# Trying to insert data with a form but get Undefined variable error

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to do an form that insert values into my database but I always get this error message for id_team, name and img:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: id_team in *** on line 12
```

So it's saying that the error come from this line:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO player (id, id_team, name, img) VALUES(NULL, $id_team, $name, $img)";
```

But I don't see any error in my insert query.

Here is my php:

```
include('../../../connexion.php');
$connexion=connexionBd();

if(isset($_POST['id_team']) && isset($_POST['name'])&& isset($_POST['img'])&& !empty($_POST['id_team'])&& !empty($_POST['name'])&& !empty($_POST['img'])){
    $id_team=$_POST['id_team'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $img=$_POST['img'];
}

$query1 = "INSERT INTO player (id, id_team, name, img) VALUES(NULL, $id_team, $name, $img)";

$query3 = "SELECT * FROM team";
$resultat3=$connexion->query($query3);
$res3=$resultat3->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And here is my form:

```
       <form method="post" action="add.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add a player</legend>

            <p>
                <label>Team</label>
                <select name="id_team">
                <?php foreach($res3 as $key => $value): ?> 
                    <option value="<?=$value['id']?>"><?=$value['name']?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

                </select>
            </p> 

            <p>
                <label>name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label>Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="img" style="width:200px; font-size:10px;" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="send" value="Envoyer" />
            </p>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: you do correctly a `if(isset(...` but after that try to insert into database, no matter if they are set or not. So put the `$query1 = "INSERT` _inside_ the `if(isset...`

Comment: The query you've posted is not the same as the one in the code block. The issue is that you're only defining `$id_team`, `$name` and `$img` if the if-statement evaluates as true, but you're later trying to use those variables regardless if they were defined or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO player (`id`, `id_team`, `name`, `img`) VALUES(NULL, '$id_team', '$name', '$img')";
```

Comment: Though it's true that the lack of quotes (specially around the values) is an issue in the OP's code, how would this solve the `undefined variable`-error the OP actually asks about?

Comment: a good answer always states _why_ you think this code could work better.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error because I forgot to put the query in the if loop so it didn't recognize the values.

```
if(isset($_POST['id_team']) && isset($_POST['name'])&& isset($_POST['img'])&& !empty($_POST['id_team'])&& !empty($_POST['name'])&& !empty($_POST['img'])){
    $id_team=$_POST['id_team'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $img=$_POST['img'];

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO player (`id`, `id_team`, `name`, `img`) VALUES(NULL, '$id_team', '$name', '$img')";

}
```